# How to make Debian's minimal bash look the same as Desktop version

Tags: bash, colors, debian

I have used virtualbox to install a **minimal** Debian version because I only want to use the bash terminal to use GIT. But the terminal looks completely different to the desktop version. I want to make it look the same as the Desktop version because it's easier to read. How do I configure this?

**update**: I have edited the ~/.bashrc file to force_color_prompt=yes and set the environment variable TERM="xterm-256color". I do get color but the text in the desktop version are all bold, where as my minimal isn't. And the background should be grey.

Screenshot: 
[Minimal Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lryqi.png) and [Desktop Bash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HopJj.png)

Answer (score 0):

It should be configured in the pseudo terminal tool, the important setting for readability is to change the ansi blue, adding some red and green, because of black background from `0 0 127` for example to `95 127 191`

Comment: I'm kinda new to this ^_^; How would I go about modifying the colour codes? I'd like some explicit step-by-step instructions to follow for Debian Stretch.

Comment: i don't have a debian environment and i don't know the tool used in "Minimal Terminal" screenshot but it should have settings which may include terminal coulours

Comment: if you go in help is there an about option to let know the tool name and version

Comment: My virtual machine is headless so without commands I don't know how to query the name of the 'tool' and its version ^_^;

Comment: I assume you mean which terminal emulator I am using?

Comment: Oh and "minimal terminal" isnt the real name of the emulator. It's actually just the caption of my screenshot

Comment: yes you still haven't give the name and version of your terminal tool

Comment: I used `echo $TERM` and it just gave me back `linux` which I'm not sure is very helpful.

Comment: where  do you take your snaphot? you have a window with a pseudo terminal with a menu bar and with help menu, inside you should have about or something?

Comment: Ahh I understand the confusion. I'm running the headless server inside VirtualBox. What you see there is the context menu for virtualbox and not the emulator 'inside' the headless server.

Comment: so the colors should configured in that tool